# SQL Server : While loop with nested If

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, while-loop

I'm creating a stock market database and am stumped that the following works correctly EXCEPT for the last select that returns results (after which the select does not change on subsequent loops). I've tried to simplify the code as follows, thanks in advance for feedback (I'm still noob):

Three tables:

- BuyOrders
- SellOrders
- MatchedOrders

Stored procedure to process a NewBuyOrder:

```
 Insert NewBuyOrder to BuyOrders;

 While (NewBuyOrder.SharesRemaining > 0 )

      SELECT TOP 1 
      FROM SellOrders 
      WHERE SellOrders.Price <= NewBuyOrder.Price
      ORDER BY SellOrders.Price, SellOrders.TimePlaced;

      IF NewBuyOrder.SharesRemaining < SellOrders.SharesAvailable 
         UPDATE SellOrders.SharesAvailable = [difference];
         UPDATE BuyOrders = 0;

         INSERT INTO MatchedOrders;

         SET NewBuyOrder.SharesRemaining = 0;
         BREAK;

     ELSE
         UPDATE SellOrders = 0;
         UPDATE BuyOrders = [difference];

         INSERT INTO MatchedOrders;

         SET NewBuyOrder.SharesRemaining = [difference];
         CONTINUE;
```

Comment: That doesn't look like MS SQL server - is that some pseudocode or did you tag this with the wrong server tag?

Comment: I'm not real familiar with the format, are we looking at pseudo code?  If not, what SQL server is this for?  I don't see any scoping (begin/end) on the where, and I don't see what you're selecting to top 1 into.   If this is MSSQL, is NewBuyOrder a CLR UDF or something?

Comment: Posted is pseudo code since (I'm using SQL Server 2008) -- I was hoping there was some obvious error with the While/Break/Continue . . .  if not I can post the entire 300 lines.

Comment: Nothing immediately jumps out as erroneous about your loop. Might have to post the full code in addition to your psuedocode to see if anything else is wrong. You should also clarify what you mean by 'last viable Select'

Answer (score 1):

In hope it might help someone else, I found the issue . . . I'm using local variables to store the matched SellOrderID.  As such if the Select returns no match on a second pass through then the local variables were not getting updated (and hence erroneously reused in subsequent while loops until the If kicked in).

So I put a SET SellOrders.ID = 0 into the WHILE loop before the Select then below the Select added a IF SellOrders.ID = 0 and inside that a SET NewBuyOrder.SharesRemaining = 0 and BREAK (then made the first IF above into an ELSE IF).

I need to revisit the process to see if I can make it more elegant but would sincerely welcome thoughts on better ways to accomplish a process for matching the best available counteroffers in sequence.  I've read but don't know much about cursors, plus think it transactionally superior not to SELECT a prioritized table of all matches rather than using my iterative loop -- but also have read suggestions not to use loops in SQL.  Comments?

---

In addition I note the following: By itself a Select with no results returns a null set.  Thus my original plan was to Select into my SP local variables and then use an IF EXISTS. I assume the local variable exists upon instantiation (even with no value) but am surprised that after a Select into the local variable with no results also did not fail an IF NULL test (i.e. presumably NULL cannot be inserted into a variable).  What then is the value of an instantiated local variable with no value --  Blank?